# How do I do a clean install of macOS Mojave?

Tags: install, mojave

I follow instructions and installed macOS Mojave on my MacBook Air. The update installed and when I try to use the new software, to my surprise, every 2 minutes the screen was frozen.

I am using Mac since I was 18 years old and I am 50 now. I know macOS and the use of software very well.

I have created a USB macOS Mojave installer and tried clean install. To my surprise it got me nowhere. I tried recovery from Internet with no luck. I partition the hard drive to journal but with no luck again.

Comment: Hello Mario, welcome to Ask Different. You write "I create a usb mojave and try clean install, to my suprise it got me nowhere" and "I tried recovery from internet no luck". Which problems have you encountered? Didn't the USB drive boot? Did you MacBook fail to start Recovery over the Internet? Have you tried https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314 and https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904?

Comment: By "no luck" do you mean that the freezing problem occurs in all of the attempts you describe? Or that the install fails before completion?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure first that your hardware is compatible with Mojave - macOS 10.14. Some sources to check:

- http://osxdaily.com/2018/06/05/macos-mojave-compatible-macs-list/
- https://www.cnet.com/how-to/here-are-the-macs-that-will-work-with-macos-mojave/

**To do a clean install of Mojave:**

1. Make a usb install drive following [these instructions](https://9to5mac.com/2018/06/18/how-to-create-a-bootable-macos-mojave-10-14-usb-install-drive-video/).
2. Back up your system drive in triplicate, or whatever you're comfortable with. Ideally one would be a literal clone of your system.
3. Boot from the USB drive, and erase your system drive in Disk Utility. Format it as HFS+.
4. Quit Disk Utility, and install Mojave on the drive you erased.

If those steps don't work, I would suspect a hardware incompatibility or problem.